# running LUA script with Wireshark

Tags: plugins, lua, directory, wireshark

I'm trying to run lua scripts with Wireshark, but i get error messages all the time when opening wireshark. I have downloaded the files from github but cant really understand how to procedd.

I've tried to put the scripts into the global lua plugins, personal lua plugins, personal plugins and global plugins. Nothing works...

Comment: the error message would be helpful

Comment: Lua: Error during loading:
...k\plugins\comm_dissector\wireshark\dji-dumlv1-camera.lua:4: attempt to index global 'DJI_DUMLv1_PROTO' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 ...k\plugins\comm_dissector\wireshark\dji-dumlv1-camera.lua:4: in main chunk

Comment: The error message is longer, but cant paste it all in

Comment: Please edit your question, and specify (with details!) the error message. Currently, there is not enough information to provide an accurate answer without guessing, and we should not guess if you can just provide this information!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I assume you are talking about [this repo](https://github.com/o-gs/dji-firmware-tools/tree/master/comm_dissector/wireshark).
The directory contains an `init.lua`, which indicates that you should launch the entire directory or the init file, as the other files depend on it.

E.g. `DJI_DUMLv1_PROTO` is a global var loaded in another file, which causes your errors.

Try to launch the directory or the `init.lua`.